# Use a gradient color fill for a bubble grid chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a bubble grid chart created but I can't for the life of my change the colors of the fill. I want to use a rainbow gradient based on the values. Below is my code and I've attached image out my output

```
setwd("C:/Users/Schelly/Desktop/Projects/Jens_tables_and_figures_2020/Bubble_chart")
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)
pc <- read.csv("Para_Bubble_data2.csv", header = TRUE)
head(pc)
pcm<-melt(pc, id = c("Sample"))
pcm$Sample <- factor(pcm$Sample,levels=unique(pcm$Sample))
xx = ggplot(pcm, aes(x = Sample, y = variable)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = value, fill = value), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4))+
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0.000001, 1), range = c(1,17), breaks = c(.01,.10,.50,.75)) + 
  labs( x= "", y = "", size = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "")
xx
```

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjLdS.png)

Comment: You want to use `scale_fill_griadientn` instead of `scale_colour_gradientn`

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `aes(colour = value)` if you want to use `scale_color_gradientn`:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = factor(rep(1:5, each = 6)), 
                 y = factor(rep(1:6, 5)), val = sample(30))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = val, colour = val)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "blue"))
```

[image]

If you want to use fill (to preserve a different outline colour), you need to use `scale_fill_gradientn`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = val)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = val, fill = val), alpha = 0.75, shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(4))+
  labs( x= "", y = "", size = "Relative Abundance (%)", fill = "")
```

[image]

Comment: You can now (since some ggplot2 2.2x release I believe) do `scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "blue"), aesthetics=c("fill", "color"))` to map to colour and fill at the same time (or `scale_color_x(aesthetics="fill")` to map just to fill.